# Returning arrow function from Vuex storage getter: Not understanding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter, arrow-functions

I have been watching one Vuex course and up until now everything was fine till they included arrow function in a getter and then using it in computed property  and action. The code is following:

item structure:

```js
const _products = [
  { id: 1, title: "iPad 4 Mini", price: 500.01, inventory: 2 },
  { id: 2, title: "H&M T-Shirt White", price: 10.99, inventory: 10 },
  { id: 3, title: "Charli XCX - Sucker CD", price: 19.99, inventory: 5 }
];
```

a getter in `store.js`:

```js
    productIsInStock() {
      return product => {
        return product.inventory > 0;
      };
    }
```

an action in `store.js` which uses this getter:

```js
    addProductToCart(context, product) {
      if (context.getters.productIsInStock(product)) {
        let cartItem = context.state.cart.find(item => item.id === product.id);
        if (!cartItem) {
          context.commit("pushProductToCart", product.id);
        } else {
          context.commit("incrementItemQuantity", cartItem);
        }
        context.commit("decrementProductInventory", product);
      }
    },
```

a computed which uses this getter and template, `ProductList.vue` :

```js
<template>
            <li v-for="(product, index) in products" v-bind:key="index">
                {{product.title}} - {{product.price | currency}} - {{product.inventory}}
                <button
                    @click="addProductToCart(product)"
                    :disabled="!productIsInStock(product)"
                >
                    Add product to cart
                </button>
            </li>
</template>
  // ...

  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.state.products;
    },
    productIsInStock() {
      return this.$store.getters.productIsInStock;
    }
  },
```

It **is** totally working but I don't understand why. Mainly I do not understand how this getter works inside both computed and if statement. I tried to repeat the same structure in the console but for some reason it didn't work at all. Hope I provided enough code

Comment: Perhaps *I'm* not clear what *you're* not clear on, but that function takes a `product`, checks if its `inventory` is greater than `0`, and returns the result - either `true` or `false`. You can think of it as `productIsInStock = (product) => product.inventory > 0;` if that helps at all.

Comment: @TylerRoper i'm not clear on: 

1) how arrow function inside the getter takes the value, isn't it just the name of a parameter?
2) as I saw in the console this getter returns function what I don't understand is how it works in the if statement, the console was always returning true no matter what mock object with inventory properties I used but outside console it works perfectly fine .

I understand that this getter filters result but I don't understand what happens from the syntax point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I understand your doubt.

productIsInStock is a getter, that returns an arrow function, and vue evaluates this in the render function, through the template part:

```
<button
     @click="addProductToCart(product)"
     :disabled="!productIsInStock(product)">
       Add product to cart
</button>
```

It's important first to understand that vue, thanks to :disable databind, evaluates the value as javascript. So it calulates the actual value of the getter (that is a function), and YOU call the actual return value (remember, is a function) that return something.

Put on another way: The getter are called everytime that related state changes, to recalculate the value, that is why you use the getter (like in `this.getterA + this.getterB`) and not CALL the getter (like `this.getterA() this.getterB()`).

If you still don't understand, check my "fake" render function that replaces the template rendering:

```
let productIsInStock = () => product => { ... }

render(h) {
 return h('button', {
   '@click': () => this.addProductToCard(product),
   ':disabled': () => productIsInStock()(product), // using arrow fn instead of the getter
 }
}
```

This is also know as currying in functional programming language.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, now I understand how it is working inside template but still don't how it is working in `if statement`. As far as I get it does not transform into `productIsInStock()(product)`. So, how this `if(store.getters.productIsInStock(product))` translates product parameter into arrow function it is returning? When I try to call just `store.getters.productIsInStock({inventory: 5})` it returns the function but as soon as I wrap it into another function like 
`function foo(product) {
if(store.getters.productIsInStock(product)) {
console.log(product);
}
}`
it works fine

Comment: Because the this.$store.getters.productIsInStock is a vue created es6 getter and not the original function in store.getters.productIsInStock, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the case. I tried to create an object with the same structure and `store.getters.productIsInStock` returns the reference to the function which returns the arrow function, while an actual Vuex store object with `store.getters.productIsInStock` returns the arrow function itself or reference to that. So, with my own object I have to use `store.getters.productIsInStock()(product)` but with the actual Vuex store object `store.getters.productIsInStock(product)` is fine. I guess I just dont get the mechanism behind this...

Comment: Alright. I just read what is ES6 getter and now I totally see it. Vuex getters have es6 getters and an actual returning value when I refer to the name of getter is what is following `return`. So. `context.getters.productIsInStock(product)` returns arrow function via es6 getter and then the returned function is called. I think the course I have been watching didn't notice a single thing about how getters actually works on the more low level. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You define getters in your store as a function. This function is called with the state, other getters (and in case of module also the root state and root getters). Based on that you return some value. Normally, that data is some value (e.g. an object, number, boolean, etc.)

```
getters: {
  numberOfPolarBears (state) {
    return state.polarBears.length;
  }
}
```

Functions in javascript do not differ much from other data. A function like this can also be defined as some variable.

```
// Method 1
function ticklePolarBear (bear) {
  bear.tickle();
}

// Method 2
var ticklePolarBear = function (bear) {
  bear.tickle();
};
```

In either case, you would call it with:

```
ticklePolarBear(frostyTheBear);
```

---

Why is this important? While when you normally map a getter and that way get some data back, nothing prevents you from mapping a getter and returning a function that you can call later.

```
getters: {
  namedPolarBear (state) {
    return function (index) {
      if (index >= state.polarBears.length) {
        return null;
      }

      return state.polarBears[index].name;
    }
  }
}
```

The arrow function sets the context of `this` differently, but is otherwise very similar to the example above.

---

`computed` in a component provides (in this case) a getter function for some attributes. In your example, it returns what the getter in your store returns, namely a function. Since it is a function, you can call it.

In this case no reactivity is going on, so you could also write the following:

```
data () {
  return {
    productIsInStock: this.$store.getters.productIsInStock
  };
}
```